# ElasticSearch combine must-match with multi-match

Tags: elasticsearch, match

I have been trying to combine MUST-MATCH with MULTI-MATCH but couldn't get it to work. Basically I want these MUST conditions:

```
 "must": [{ "match": { "city": $city } },
          { "match": { "is_displayed": 1 } },
          { "match": { "status": "active" } }]
```

and I want these matches:

```
            "multi_match": {
                "query": $query,
                "type": $selectedType,
                "fields": fieldArray,
            }
```

where $query is the textbox values $selectedType is one of the multi-match query types and fieldArray is the fields to search for. For example, when the text box value is "hello world" and fieldArray is ['title', 'cuisine'], either "hello" and/or "world" must match  either or all of the specified fields. Any insight and advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I guess adding another clause in `must` block will do the needful.

```
{
 "query": {
  "bool": {
     "must": [
        {
           "match": {
              "city": "$city"
           }
        },
        {
           "match": {
              "is_displayed": 1
           }
        },
        {
           "match": {
              "status": "active"
           }
        },

         "query_string": {
          "fields": fieldArray,
          "query": "*$query*"
         }
        }
       ]
     }
    }
   }
```

Comment: I tried that but only phrase_prefix has results returned. The other multi-match query types returned empty result set.

Comment: Where is `phrase_prefix`  query??

Comment: It's in the $selectedType variable. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html

Comment: Ok I Got It. `The other multi-match query types returned empty result set` .. What does this mean? You will get only one result for one query. Above query will  apply `AND`  operation in all the clauses.

Comment: I was trying to use partial string matching. I expected $query ('i') would return results which has 'i' in any of the specified field $fieldArray. How can I possibly achieve this? Thanks!